# how to find the worng spot in the given image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, image, touch

I have one doubt, that is i have working the simply find the image difference. I an displaying two images one is correct image other one wrong image with three difference, then user has to find the difference by touching the right spot.

What are the ways it can be implemented with good programing. please suggest your solution. I am unable to follow the right approach.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Comment: If you use the images bounds then the spot where the changes are should be at exactly the same coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving each image can have a transparent overlay "map" with coordinates to the changes?